# BLE device gives me a number on reading a particular characteristic service. What is the value return type?

Tags: ios, hex, decimal, bluetooth-lowenergy

I connected to BLE device using BLE Scanner. And on reading a characteristics which is R/W. The value is 0x1e000000

What is this value and is there a way to convert this to decimal value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of a particular GATT value is specified by the documentation of the GATT service. Type information is not included in the transmission.

Sometimes however there is a format descriptor for the characteristic that describes the data type that can be read.